# Transmit data to an adress stm32CubeIde

Tags: c++, stm32, uart, stm32cubeide

I am newly working on Stm32CubeIde and I am trying to understand how it works. I would like to transmit data to a specific address using the UART port and I don't know how to do it. So far I have been able to transmit using these three methods:

**using the poll —> HAL_UART_Transmit**

**using the interrupt —> HAL_UART_Transmit_IT**

**using DMA —> HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA**

but none of them in their implementation refer to transmitting to a specific address.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UART hardware will transmit a series of high a low voltages onto the wire. RS232 and RS422 are full duplex so there is only a single receiver. RS485 is half duplex so there can be multiple receivers listening to the same data. How that data is framed including which receiver the data is for depends on the higher level protocol like Modbus